# Cannot remove double quotes from a list element using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove from some list elements some extra double quotes by using strip or replace but they are not removed. I am using the following

```
with open(source_initial2, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1',newline='') as csvf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                if "\"" in row[i]:
                    row[i].replace('\"','')  
            igecontents.append(row)

return igecontents
```

The row in csv is like the following:

```
DCA.P/C.06190;7613329007877;WENGER, COBALT 16 COMPUTER BACKPACK;" BLUE (R)""";35,92;Yes
DCA.P/C.06191;7613329007914;WENGER, PILLAR 16 COMPUTER BACKPACK;" BLACK/GRAY (R)""";35,92;No
```

Comment: Who is igecontents?

Comment: The igecontents is a list not a person :)

Comment: Of course - I still don't really know what it's got to do with your code snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'r') as csvf:
    output = []
    for row in csvf.readlines():
        output.append(row.replace('\"', ''))

with open('outfile','a') as f:
    f.writelines(output)
```

COntent of outfile:

```
DCA.P/C.06190;7613329007877;WENGER, COBALT 16 COMPUTER BACKPACK; BLUE (R);35,92;Yes
DCA.P/C.06191;7613329007914;WENGER, PILLAR 16 COMPUTER BACKPACK; BLACK/GRAY (R);35,92;No
```

You have some extras bits in your code that are unecessary - like checking if the quotes are in the line or not.... Also no need for a reader object - you've already opened the file with the with open(...") as csvf statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` function of a str object in python return a new str, and doesn't modify the object that call it, so what you should do is

```
row[i] = row[i].replace('\"','')
```